# Error when trying to uninstall BurnAware from the Control Panel

Tags: windows, uninstall, windows-installer

I want to uninstall BurnAware so I go to the Control Panel -> Programs and Features and double-click on the entry for BurnAware but I get the following error:

[image: Error messsage]

How can I uninstall it?

Comment: Control Panel simply runs the uninstaller the program registered when it was installed.  If the uninstaller is broken or corrupt then you have to uninstall it another way.  The simplest solution, install the software again, and choose the option to remove the installation instead of actually installing it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Error when trying to uninstall BurnAware from the Control Panel

You can clean up the leftovers using [IObit Uninstaller 3](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html).

> IObit Uninstaller 3 is a light and FREE uninstall tool that helps you
> to remove unwanted programs and leftovers completely without any
> hassle. It detects and categorizes all of the installed programs, and
> allows bulk uninstallation with just ONE click!

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with IObit in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue but with another program. I have used Microsoft's "Fix It" which worked for me. You can download the tool from :- http://support.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en .

Once downloaded Launch the application and follow the instruction.

Let me know how it goes.